# Настройка брандмауэра Windows для приложения

Tags: windows, безопасность

Как сделать что бы запретить доступ в Интернет ко всем программам кроме Google Chrome?

Comment: Вы имеете в виду программным путём?

Comment: @0xdb, вряд ли. Скорее это вопрос по администированию. К тому же заголовок же есть.

Comment: Версия ОС? Встроенный брандмауэр или от антивируса какого? "Всем программам" это пользовательским или системные тоже порезать хотите? Как-то маловато информации даже для ТЗ.

Comment: в общих чертах, вам нужно прописать запрещающее правило (или отключить разрешающее) на выход для всех портов кроме 53(DNS), 80(HTTP), 443(HTTPS). Уточните вопрос, будет более точный ответ. Список портов по-умолчанию для протоколов [тут](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2_TCP_%D0%B8_UDP)

Answer (score 0):

Если речь идет о встроенном брандмауэре, то нужно изменить его правила.
Предварительно можно сохранить действующую конфигурацию (например, в файл old.wfw) следующей командой:

```
netsh advfirewall export c:\temp\old.wfw
```

Вернуть правила обратно, соответственно:

```
netsh advfirewall import c:\temp\old.wfw
```

Затем можно удалить все активные правила или отключить их.
После этого нужно перевести брандмауэр в режим блокировки всех соединений:

```
netsh advfirewall set currentprofile firewallpolicy blockinbound,blockoutbound
```

Затем нужно добавить правило для DNS-запросов  (если нужно)

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="DNSquery" dir=out action=allow protocol=UDP remoteport=53  enable=yes
```

И, наконец, правило для работы браузера (для 32-разрядной версии Windows):

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Browser" dir=out action=allow program="%ProgramFiles%\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" protocol=any enable=yes
```

P.S.
Если необходима правильная работа автоконфигурации IP-протокола сетевых интерфейсов, можно оставить активными правила относящиеся к работе DHCP-протокола.
P.P.S. Для восстановления дефолтной конфигурации брандмауэра нужно воспользоваться командой

```
netsh advfirewall reset
```

Не забываем, что указанные команды управления исполняются в консоли с правами администратора и являются действительными только для брандмауэров операционных систем платформ NT6 (старше XP/Srv2003)