# Как заблокировать трафик для всех приложений, кроме TeamViewer?

Tags: windows, firewall, teamviewer

Есть удаленная машина, к которой мне нужно подключаться и контролировать работу системы. Подключение происходит по TeamViewer. При этом нужно сделать так, чтобы никакие больше программы не имели выхода в Интернет. Как это проще всего и правильнее сделать? ОС Windows 10.

Comment: Штатным фаерволлом пробовал?

Comment: Подобное [решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/710987/) было опробовано?

Comment: Вроде разобрался со штатным, спасибо. Использовал эту статью https://habrahabr.ru/post/275549/